# How to expand a multidimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays

It has an array `CriticalArray` that is used all over the application, possibly by multiple threads.
The size of this array sometimes need to expanded based on user actions. When the size needs to be dramatically increased, the code below takes minutes to execute.
Is there a way to expand the size of the array in more efficient way?

```
Data[,] CriticalArray = new Data[COLS,ROWS];
```

The usual value is `COLS` = 50 and `ROWS` = 3000. When expanding the dimensions can become become 50, 90000.

This is the expansion code causing the delay:

```
Data[,] TempCriticalArray = new Data[COLS, DELTA + ROWS];

for (int i = 0; i < COLS; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++)
    TempCriticalArray[i, j] = CriticalArray[i, j];

CriticalArray = TempQuoteStore;
```

Comment: Try using a list instead of an array. it will automatically expand and be much more efficent.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET OP is using a multi dimensional array.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel True You can still make that work with a List (or a List of Lists), but it does complicate the situation.

Comment: I agree with @BradleyDotNET. An array is the wrong collection type in this case.

Comment: It seems to me only the number of rows is changed (since the presence of `DELTA`). If that's the case, a `List<Data[]>` may fit, where each list element is a row.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET True, but that more or less gives a jagged array. Not multi dimensional array. `List<T>` with a custom type would be better.

Comment: What is the structure of the object `Data`? 50x90000 = 4500000 slots allocated. It seems a lot of memory.

Comment: When you allocate an matrix of 50*9000 and store objects inside them (I assume x64) then alone emtpy objects must consume 10,8GB of memory. No wonder why this operation takes minutes if you need to load the data from somewhere for 450 million objects.

Comment: Is the data stored in your array dense (every element contains a meaningful value) or sparse (most elements are null at any given point in time)?  If the latter, you may want to research [Sparse Matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) for some ideas on how to represent them more efficiently.

Comment: Then the source of the time consumption is most likely swapping all that gigabytes to disk.

Comment: what is the datatype of Data...? can you not do something like this 
`string[,] TempCriticalArray = {};` and if you were to have a List<data> populate it and then assign `TempCriticalArray = List<Data> variable.ToArray()`;

Answer (score 2):

As you might have noticed already, the usual `Array.Resize` does not work for multidimensional arrays.

Since you are not changing the number of columns, you could use `Array.Copy` (note that the instance method `array.CopyTo` does not support multidimensional arrays).

Note from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When copying between multidimensional arrays, the array behaves like a
>   long one-dimensional array, where the rows (or columns) are
>   conceptually laid end to end. For example, if an array has three rows
>   (or columns) with four elements each, copying six elements from the
>   beginning of the array would copy all four elements of the first row
>   (or column) and the first two elements of the second row (or column).

```
Data[,] CriticalArray = new Data[COLS,ROWS];
Data[,] TempCriticalArray = new Data[COLS, DELTA + ROWS];

Array.Copy(CriticalArray, TempCriticalArray, CriticalArray.Length);

CriticalArray = TempCriticalArray
```

This is probably as fast as copying arrays get in C#, but if you have to move 10 GB of data around you have to expect some lag nonetheless...

You could also consider using another data structure or changing your design, if possible, to not require loading that many items at once.

Comment: and then add this line in the end?? CriticalArray = TempQuoteStore;

Comment: ? Where does TempQuoteStore come from? You're using TempCriticalArray in your question... EDIT: Ah I see on the last line. But still, where does that come from? How is it different from TempCriticalArray?

Comment: @bsobaid `Array.Copy` copies the content of the array into the target, you don't need to reassign anything.

Comment: typo, yes it is  CriticalArray = TempQuoteStore . In your example the size of CriticalArray array is not changing. If I add this last line then it will be.

Comment: grrrr... it is CriticalArray = TempCriticalArray

Comment: Oh right ok I see what you mean. Yes you need to reassign to change the orignal array... Sorry about that

Comment: Just tried. Strangely, Array.copy appears to be as slow if not slower than the original method

Answer (score 0):

You could also change the data structure so you never need to copy data around but you simply append data to it. That would mean that you need to implement the indexer by yourself which could slow down index access a bit but then you would be much faster when adding rows to your matrix while keeping the column count fixed. 
Here is a draft of a LinkedList which shows the idea although some bounds errors might still be inside it:

```
class LinkedMatrix<T>
{
    int LowerY;
    int UpperY;

    public int TotalColums
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    LinkedMatrix<T> Next;

    T[,] InternalArray;

    public LinkedMatrix(int rows, int cols)
    {
        InternalArray = new T[rows, cols];
        UpperY = rows;
        TotalColums = cols;
    }

    private LinkedMatrix(int lowerY, int addedRows, int colums)
    {
        InternalArray = new T[addedRows, colums];
        LowerY = lowerY;
        UpperY = LowerY + addedRows;
    }

    public void AppendRows(int addedRows)
    {
        LinkedMatrix<T> LastNotNull = this;
        while( LastNotNull.Next != null )
        {
            LastNotNull = LastNotNull.Next;
        }

        LastNotNull.Next = new LinkedMatrix<T>(LastNotNull.UpperY, addedRows, this.TotalColums);
    }

    public T this[int y, int x]
    {
        get
        {
            if( y >= UpperY  )
            {
                if( Next != null)
                {
                    return Next[y, x];
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
                }
            }
            else if( y >= LowerY )
            {
                return InternalArray[y - LowerY, x];
            }
            else
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }

        set
        {
            if (y >= UpperY)
            {
                if (Next != null)
                {
                    Next[y,x] = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
                }
            }
            else if (y >= LowerY)
            {
                InternalArray[y - LowerY, x] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LinkedMatrix<string> matrix = new LinkedMatrix<string>(1, 1);
        matrix[0, 0] = "0,0";
        matrix.AppendRows(1);
        matrix[1, 0] = "1,0";
    }
}
```